# create new array with fixed date array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi please help me to combine the two array
I want to find the combined array with the sum of count values and create new array as mentioned in the output

> Is any possible to do like this array2 will be fixed size and date is
> generated in array2 is from the current date to last 7 days

this is array 1

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => failed
            [date] => 2021-05-17
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => failed
            [date] => 2021-05-12
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => failed
            [date] => 2021-05-04
            [count] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => failed
            [date] => 2021-05-03
            [count] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [status] => success
            [date] => 2021-05-17
            [count] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [status] => no result publish
            [date] => 2021-05-17
            [count] => 9
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [status] => no result publish
            [date] => 2021-05-11
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

array 2

```
Array
(
[0] => 2021-05-18
[1] => 2021-05-17
[2] => 2021-05-16
[3] => 2021-05-15
[4] => 2021-05-14
[5] => 2021-05-13
[6] => 2021-05-12
[7] => 2021-05-11
)
```

output for the comabain

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => failed
            [2021-05-18]=>0
            [2021-05-17] => 1
            [2021-05-16]=>0
            [2021-05-15]=>0
            [2021-05-14]=>0
            [2021-05-13]=>0
            [2021-05-12]=>1
            [2021-05-11]=>0
            [geaterdays]=> 3 // sum of count greater than 7 days from current date
            [grandTotal] => 5 // sum of all date counts
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => success
            [2021-05-18]=>0
            [2021-05-17] => 1
            [2021-05-16]=>0
            [2021-05-15]=>0
            [2021-05-14]=>0
            [2021-05-13]=>0
            [2021-05-12]=>0
            [2021-05-11]=>0
            [geaterdays]=> 0 // sum of count greater than 7 days from current date
            [grandTotal] => 1 // sum of all date counts
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => no result publish
            [2021-05-18]=>0
            [2021-05-17] => 9
            [2021-05-16]=>0
            [2021-05-15]=>0
            [2021-05-14]=>0
            [2021-05-13]=>0
            [2021-05-12]=>0
            [2021-05-11]=>1
            [geaterdays]=> 0 // sum of count greater than 7 days from current date
            [grandTotal] => 10 // sum of all date counts
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your script.

Comment: Is there any logic in how you get from the first two array to the expected output? I can't see it.